# R reverse function to solve for parameter when output is a fixed constant

Tags: r, function, purrr, equation, equation-solving

If I have a function

```
estimator <- function(A,B) {
 A*(B+23)
}
```

How can I reverse this function to find the value of A for B as a sequence between 0 and 120 (B=1,2,3,4,...,120) that would give a fixed result, say C = 20?

I would use it to map the values for  which satisfy the equation A*(B+23)= C = 20 with B being a list b.list between 0 and 120, for c.list, of different C?

```
b.list <- seq(0,120,by=1)
c.list <- tibble(seq(10,32,by=2))
```

In the end, I would like to plot the lines of curves of the function for different C using purrr or similar.

I.e.: Given that the height of a tree in metres at age 100 will follow the function, C = A*(B+23), solve for A that will give the result  C=10 when B, *Age* is a list of years between 0 and 120?

**Here's a link showing what I'm trying to make!**
[image]

**Here's another one**

[image]
Many thanks!

Comment: In your graph what is A ? Is it the height ?

Comment: @RémiCoulaud see comment to your answer.

Comment: Is this answer helping you ?

Comment: I am consulting with a researcher who has experience on the issue and will come back Monday.

Comment: I'm sorry but I repeat my question is this answer helping you ?

Answer (score 0):

For the inverse it is a quick inversion :

```
A = C/(B+23)
```

One answer could be :

```
B <- seq(0, 120)
C <- seq(10, 32, 2)
A <- matrix(0,
            nrow = length(B),
            ncol = length(C))

for(i in 1:ncol(M)){
    A[,i] <- C[i] / (B + 23)
}

matplot(B, A, type ="l", col = "black")
```

In case of a more complex function indeed you need an automatic solving problem. One way is to see it like an optimisation problem where you want to minimise the distance from C :

```
B <- seq(1, 120)
C <- seq(10, 32, 2)
A <- matrix(0,
            nrow = length(B),
            ncol = length(C))
fct <- function(A, B, C){
    paramasi <- 25
    parambeta<- 7395.6
    paramb2 <- -1.7829
    refB <- 100
    d <- parambeta*(paramasi^paramb2)
    r <- (((A-d)^2)+(4*parambeta*A*(B^paramb2)))^0.5
    si_est <- (A+d+r)/ (2+(4*parambeta*(refB^paramb2)) / (A-d+r))
    return(sum(si_est - C)^2)}

for(c in 1:length(C)){
    for(b in 1:length(B)){
        # fixe parameters + optimisation
        res <- optim(par = 1, fn = fct, B = B[b], C = C[c])
        A[b, c] <- res$par
    }
}

matplot(B, A, type = "l", col = "black")
```

You need to be careful because in your case I think that you could find an analytical formula for the inverse which would be better.

Good luck !

Comment: Well yes, this inverts the formula, but not the function! A is not really a parameter.  The real formula would be the inverse of a function for one species, approximation of the site index (the height of a tree at a reference age, e.g. 100)  ?```function(topheight, age){
  paramasi <- 25
  parambeta <- 7395.6
  paramb2 <- -1.7829
  refAge <- 100
  
  d <- parambeta*(paramasi^paramb2)
  
  r <- (((topheight-d)^2)+(4*parambeta*topheight*(age^paramb2)))^0.5
  
  si_est<- (topheight+d+r)/ (2+(4*parambeta*(refAge^paramb2)) / (topheight-d+r))
  
  return(si_est)
}```

Comment: Be careful the result of your function need to be a vector whereas you only give a result under the form of a constant : 20